# Is it necessary to keep open a excel file, while importing data to data table, C#

Tags: c#

**My connection string is:**

```
String excelConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("abc.xls") + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0; HDR=YES;IMEX=1'";

OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(excelConn);  
Conn.Open();
```

It gives an error, like “**Could not decrypt file.**” If my Excel file (abc.xls) is close in my client PC. But it is ok when my excel file is open.

Comment: Is the excel file protected using some password?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you cannot connect to a password protected excel file with OleDbConnection, it won't work by design.

Check here: [Open a password-protected Excel workbook](http://www.connectionstrings.com/Articles/Show/how-to-open-password-protected-excel-workbook)

> If you try to open a password-protected Excel workbook from Access,
>   you get an error message “Could not decrypt file”. Adding a Password=
>   value to your connection string won’t work either. You could open it
>   as an Excel application, but then you’d have to learn about the Excel
>   object model and all you want to do is read it row-by-row as you would
>   any unprotected Excel file.
>
> To get around this problem, first open the Excel workbook using
>   GetObject() and then open it using the connection / recordset approach
>   that you want to use. The GetObject() open prompts your user for the
>   password, and then you are free to open the file using your preferred
>   approach.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your file is password protected. Please confirm the same. The password protected file can not be opened even by supplying password in connection string. Check the link http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel

The workaround is at [connection strings website](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel)